# Is every effective extension of ZF conservatively extendable to a finitely axiomatized extension of GB set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Is the following statement correct?

"Every consistent recursively axiomatized theory that extends $\sf ZF$ can be conservatively extended into a finitely axiomatized theory that extends Godel-Berney set theory".

I personally think this might be false, because there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ many theories extending $\sf ZF$, while we have countably many finitely axiomatized theories extending $\sf GB$.

> If there is an excess, then what are examples of effective extensions of $\sf ZF$ that cannot be conservatively extended into finite extensions of $\sf GB$?

Comment: There are countably many recursive extensions of $\mathsf{ZF}$, so your thought does not result in any meaningful conclusion.

Comment: @HanulJeon, Nice! So, it is possible that all of them can be extended conservatively into finite extensions of GB?